# How to integrate a device with custom API calls?

Tags: fiware

We would like to add an IoT device which uses specific API calls / responses, and we would like to know the best way to do it. Can we do this integration using the FIWARE JSON IoT Agent? We have to develop a custom FIWARE IoT Agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a JSON payload (or you can create one) then the JSON IoT Agent is a good baseline to start from. There are two basic approaches:

1. [Gateway Solution](https://fiware-academy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrated-courses/webinars/index.html#48-iot-agent-gateways-using-the-iota-tangle-for-secure-data-transfer)
2. [Custom IoT Agent](https://fiware-academy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrated-courses/webinars/index.html#33-customizing-iot-agents)

In the first approach you could create a  separate gateway component which listens to your API and it reads and interprets **measures** and posts back onto an MQTT topic `/attrs`. For **commands**, the gateway receives a JSON payload on `/cmdExe` MQTT topic and sends it on using your API. Your gateway would be responsible for marshalling/unmarshalling payloads.

In the second approach, you are writing your own IoT Agent. Effectively you are responsible for creating your own binding mapping to your API.

The advantage of the Gateway Solution is that you can continue to upgrade using the standard IoT Agent, so you will get bug fixes for free. The custom IoT Agent may be cleaner architecturally - you don't (ab)use MQTT as a message bus - but keeping the custom IoT Agent updated becomes your responsibility.

In general, I would recommend that a custom IoT Agent is used whenever the protocol is in wide enough use that multiple end-users and developers could benefit from it. Custom IoT Agents can also be developed if there are a large number of extra dependencies involved. Most IoT Agents are developed in Node.js

For a single proprietary API, gateway is probably better. If you look at the accompanying video, you'll see that in the IOTA case, both the payload and the transport are customised. A Gateway could be developed in any code language (provided it has an MQTT client available.)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Jason. We're going to use the first approach.

Comment: Is there any document or example source code about it?

Comment: Sample gateway code: https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.IoT-over-IOTA

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @jason-fox. We have just finished the development of our custom gateway and we're trying to test it. We've just created the service group into the IoT JSON Agent:

```
"services": [
        {
            "apikey": "our-api-key",
            "protocol": [
                "IoTA-JSON"
            ],
            "cbroker": "url-context-broker:1026",
            "entity_type": "Device",
            "resource": "/iot/shelly/json"
        }
      ]
```

And provisioning the device:

```
"devices": [
        {
            "device_id": "shelly003",
            "entity_name": "shelly-xxxx",
            "entity_type": "Device",
            "protocol": "IoTA-JSON",
            "transport": "HTTP",
            "endpoint": "gateway-url",
            "commands": [
                {
                    "name": "turn",
                    "type": "command"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

We're trying to send command to the device via Context Broker sending the following body to the endpoint:

```
"turn": {
      "type" : "command",
      "value" : "on"
  }
```

But we're getting always error. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: If you are copying the [Gateway Solution](https://fiware-academy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrated-courses/webinars/index.html#48-iot-agent-gateways-using-the-iota-tangle-for-secure-data-transfer) video, you should notice that I need to provision my devices as MQTT, not HTTP. The video describes why in more detail.